# Thorn symbol("þ") not working with pig script

Tags: utf-8, apache-pig, delimiter, extended-ascii

My input data is having thorn symbol("þ"). 
I am trying to split that data in  pig custom loader based on that thorn symbol.
Here i am calling that custom loader from a pig script file to which i am passing this symbol as a parameter.
If i run same code form pig shell, the symbol is being recognized but if i run that code from pig script file then symbol in data and the symbol which i am passing are differing with each other.

For example:
    `My data is : "abcþdefþghi"`

From pig shell data is read as: `abc�def�ghi`

From pig shell symbol is read as: `� and hex value is: fffd, decimal value: 65533`

From pig script file data is read as: `abc�def�ghi`

From pig script file symbol is read as: `þ and hex value is: fe, decimal value: 254`

Answer (score 0):

It fixed for me...
From pig My data is coming in ISO_8859_1 charset.
SO i changed my delimiter charset to ISO_8859_1 by using following code.

```
new String(StandaradCharset.forName("ISO_8859_1").encode(<delimiter>).toArray());
```